# Doctrine not loading annotations from my entities

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm trying to load Doctrine entities but it keeps creating the tables without any regard for the annotations I've provided.  What I really want to do is put a unique constraint on `$email` but just to prove something's funny, I changed the size of the `$email` field to 200.
I'm trying to run the `./vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema:create --dump-sql`.  I get the following output:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    unverifiedEmail VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
    unverifiedEmailHash VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
    passwordHash VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    passwordResetHash VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I formatted it pretty, but changed nothing else.

Here's my entity at `vendor/redacted/user-entity/src/User.php`

```
namespace Redacted\User\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @var int
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="unverifiedEmail", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $unverifiedEmail;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="unverifiedEmailHash", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $verifyEmailHash;

    /**
     * @var string
     * At this time, http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php recommends using 255 length for hashes
     * @ORM\Column(name="passwordHash", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $passwordHash;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="passwordResetHash", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $passwordResetHash;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUnverifiedEmail()
    {
        return $this->unverifiedEmail;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $unverifiedEmail
     */
    public function setUnverifiedEmail($unverifiedEmail)
    {
        $this->unverifiedEmail = $unverifiedEmail;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getVerifyEmailHash()
    {
        return $this->verifyEmailHash;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $verifyEmailHash
     */
    public function setVerifyEmailHash($verifyEmailHash)
    {
        $this->verifyEmailHash = $verifyEmailHash;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $email
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPasswordHash()
    {
        return $this->passwordHash;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $passwordHash
     */
    public function setPasswordHash($passwordHash)
    {
        $this->passwordHash = $passwordHash;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPasswordResetHash(): string
    {
        return $this->passwordResetHash;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $passwordResetHash
     */
    public function setPasswordResetHash(string $passwordResetHash)
    {
        $this->passwordResetHash = $passwordResetHash;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        return [
            'email' => $this->getEmail(),
            'id' => $this->getId()
        ];
    }
}
```

And here's my `cli-config.php`.

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$paths = array(__DIR__."/vendor/redacted/user-entity/src");
$isDevMode = false;

// the connection configuration
$dbParams = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user'     => 'root',
    'password' => 'redacted',
    'dbname'   => 'user'
);

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode, null, null, false);
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

return ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);
```

One more thing I should mention: I have never got this working before in several projects.  We just have so many on the go and they all have this issue and I'm getting around to resolve it, but I did have this working in tons of ZF2 projects, but they don't share this setup scheme.

Comment: Probably the metadata is cached, try clearing that place. The fact that you have columns means Doctrine read your annotations, it's just not seeing changes to it

Comment: `$isDevMode = false;`  Thanks @malarzm

Answer (score 0):

As @malarzm said above, you may need to clear your cache. Here are the commands I run any time I change doctrine configurations in my ZF2 app:

```
rm -Rf data/DoctrineModule/cache/*
rm -Rf data/DoctrineORMModule/Proxy/*
```